# Garbled test result output from meteortesting:mocha

Tags: testing, meteor, mocha.js

The recommended testing framework for Meteor 1.7 seems to be `meteortesting:mocha`.

With Meteor 1.7.0.3 I created a default app (`meteor create my-app`), which has the following tests (in `test/main.js`)

```
import assert from "assert";

describe("my-app", function () {
  it("package.json has correct name", async function () {
    const { name } = await import("../package.json");
    assert.strictEqual(name, "noteit");
  });

  if (Meteor.isClient) {
    it("client is not server", function () {
      assert.strictEqual(Meteor.isServer, false);
    });
  }

  if (Meteor.isServer) {
    it("server is not client", function () {
      assert.strictEqual(Meteor.isClient, false);
    });
  }
});
```

I ran

```
meteor add meteortesting:mocha
meteor test --driver-package meteortesting:mocha
```

and with `meteortesting:mocha`@2.4.5_6 I got this in the console:

```
I20180728-12:06:37.729(2)? --------------------------------
I20180728-12:06:37.729(2)? ----- RUNNING SERVER TESTS -----
I20180728-12:06:37.729(2)? --------------------------------
I20180728-12:06:37.729(2)? 
I20180728-12:06:37.730(2)? 
I20180728-12:06:37.731(2)? 
I20180728-12:06:37.737(2)?   the server
    ✓ fails a test.753(2)? 
I20180728-12:06:37.755(2)? 
I20180728-12:06:37.756(2)? 
I20180728-12:06:37.756(2)?   1 passing (26ms)
I20180728-12:06:37.756(2)? 
I20180728-12:06:37.757(2)? Load the app in a browser to run client tests, or set the TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER environment variable. See https://github.com/meteortesting/meteor-mocha/blob/master/README.md#run-app-tests
=> Exited with code: 0
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Actually, it was repeated three times. Not pretty. And I wasn't expecting a passing test to crash my app.

Also in the browser I got this

[image]

I was expecting something more like the nice output, as per the [Meteor testing guide](https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most things Node.js, there are a multitude of forks of almost anything. So also with `meteortesting:mocha`.

`cultofcoders:mocha` seems to be [a few commits ahead](https://github.com/cult-of-coders/meteor-mocha) of `practicalmeteor:mocha`, which was at one point the recommended testing framework for Meteor.

If you run

```
meteor add cultofcoders:mocha
meteor test --driver-package cultofcoders:mocha
```

you'll get the nice output.

As a curiousity, I found that the version of `cultofcoders:mocha` I got (`meteor list | grep mocha`) was 2.4.6, a version that the github repo does not have...

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot, you reference to, is made using `practicalmeteor:mocha`, but `meteortesting:mocha` is not (as the other answer claims) a fork of it but a separately developed package, aiming for the same goal, which is running of tests in Meteor.

The usage of the packages is very different and `practicalmeteor:mocha` might look a bit trickier to set up and this list only applies to it's version `1.0.1` and might change later.

But I have to admit that the documentation needs a refresh ... Anyways, here are some helpful tipps which I'll include in the documentation soon.

If you just want to get started, run this:

```
meteor add meteortesting:mocha
npm i --save-dev puppeteer@^1.5.0
TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER=puppeteer meteor test --driver-package meteortesting:mocha --raw-logs --once
```

---

**Do you want to exit after the tests are completed or re-run them after file-change?**

Usually, Meteor will restart your application when it exits (a normal exit or a crash), which includes the test-runner.

In case you want to use it in one of your CI or you just want to run the tests once, add [`--once`](https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html#command-line) to the meteor-command, otherwise set `TEST_WATCH=1` before running this script. If you don't set the env variable, and don't define `--once`, Meteor will print these lines and restart the tests once they're finished:

```
=> Exited with code: 0
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

As of now I haven't found a way to check if the flag `--once` is set, which would omit the env variable. The flexibility here to choose between CI and continuous testing is very useful.

Maybe you're currently working on a feature and want to run the tests as you work. If you have set `TEST_WATCH=1` and are not using `--once`, Meteor will restart the tests once it registers that a file was changed. You can even limit the test collection using `MOCHA_GREP`.

---

**Where and how do you want to see the results?**

You currently have to choose between seeing all the test-results on the command-line or to show the server-tests in the commandline and the client-tests in the browser. Currently `practicalmeteor:mocha` does not support showing the result of the server- and client-tests in the browser, as your screenshot shows.

Please take a look at the package documentation for further details:

---

**You should disable the Meteor timestamp to make it look better.**

Tests might look quite gambled because of the timestamp added to every line. To avoid this, add `--raw-logs` to your command.

---

I hope this answers most of your question. I know that the documentation needs some improvements and would welcome if someone would take the time to take it into a more logical order for people who "just want to get started".